# Jenkins multibranch tags view limit to only latest 10 tags

Tags: jenkins, devops, multibranch-pipeline, jenkins-dsl

I have jenkins multibranch setup, with tag discovery trait. From the folder view, i have the `Tags(n)` view that currrently shows all tags ever pushed to that particular repo in git.

I tried the following dsl, which only works for `branches` for obvious reasons that branches can be deleted or become stale, but not tags (unless i delete the tags, which won't happen):

```
orphanedItemStrategy {
  defaultOrphanedItemStrategy {
    pruneDeadBranches(true)
    daysToKeepStr("7")
    numToKeepStr("10")
  }

  discardOldItems {
    daysToKeep(7)
    numToKeep(10)
  }
}
```

I have combed through jenkins dsl and job config.xml, and i cannot find where to update in my dsl script or in config.xml to only show the latest 10 tags.